# Sencha Touch DatePicker Issue

Tags: extjs, touch

I added a datepicker xtype in a panel. it is working fine in all devices expect one android device- sony experia with version 4.0.4 while scrolling up for selecting year.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Which Sony Xperia device, could you mention a name and software version.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue for me in the device Sony Xperia E Model number C1604, android V4.0.4